# Spring CRUD Repository Statement with Multiple Distinct Columns and Seperate Filter

Tags: spring, select, repository, spring-data, crud

I am trying to reproduce the following SELECT using Spring CRUD Repository syntax:

```
select distinct column_1, column_2 from TABLE  where column_3 = 1
```

I've tried the following, without success:

**Returns all the records matching *value* - Distinct is ignored**

```
findDistinctColumn_1Column_2FromTableByColumn_3(Integer value)
```

**Returns all the records matching *value* - Distinct is ignored**

```
findDistinctTableColumn_1Column_2ByColumn_3(Integer value)
```

**Doesn't compile as I only want to filter on Column_3**

```
findDistinctTableByColumn_1AndColumn_2AndColumn_3(Integer value)
```

How should the Spring CRUD repository be constructed to return the same values as the SQL equivalent?

Comment: Have not found a solution to the question, but I have found a solution to the problem, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Distinct keyword is ignored. Instead, this can be accomplished using the `@Query` annotation and specifying a JPQL such as:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT p.column_1, p.column_2 from Table p where p.column_3 = ?1")
public String[] findDistinctColumn_1Column_2FromTableByColumn_3(Integer value);
```